# updating list in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this code snippet : I was expecting the output to be [1,1] when I print the list but I'm getting [0,0]. Since I have already initialised a and b as list variables , I thought the value of "result" would be updated to the values of a and b after the loop. My program is working fine if I return the values a and b but I was just wondering why the "result" isn't getting updated. I'm still learning Python so would appreciate any help

> ```
> a=0
> b=0
> arrayA=[7,9,1]
> arrayB=[2,9,5]
> result=[a,b]
>
> for i in range(0,len(arrayA)): 
>     if(arrayA[i]>arrayB[i]):
>         a+=1           
>     elif (arrayA[i]==arrayB[i]):
>         continue            
>     else:
>         b+=1
> print(result)
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Thank you!

Comment: `a` and `b` are integers.

Comment: ... that's why "result" is never updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result = [a,b], the variables a and b are not references.

```
a=0
b=0
arrayA=[7,9,1]
arrayB=[2,9,5]


for i in range(0,len(arrayA)): 
    if(arrayA[i]>arrayB[i]):
        a+=1           
    elif (arrayA[i]==arrayB[i]):
        continue            
    else:
        b+=1

result=[a,b]
print(result)
```

Would be what you want

Comment: As a sidenote, you can (and should) use `zip`, here:

`for x, y in zip(arrayA, arrayB): if x > y...`

Comment: @Lucretiel There's no real reason to use `zip`, if `zip` were used you might as well 1 line it: `result = [sum(map(lambda a: a[0] > a[1], zip(arrayA,arrayB))), sum(map(lambda a: a[0] > a[1], zip(arrayB,arrayA)))]`

Comment: I like zip because it removes the unnecessary variable index, even in for loops. Unlike the oneliner, which is slightly less readable, the zip has no impact on readability.

Answer (score 1):

complected objects like list (and more) get passed by reference, so this will get you the answer you want

```
a=[0]
b=[0]
arrayA=[7,9,1]
arrayB=[2,9,5]
result=[a,b]

for i in range(0,len(arrayA)): 
    if(arrayA[i]>arrayB[i]):
        a[0]+=1           
    elif (arrayA[i]==arrayB[i]):
        continue            
    else:
        b[0]+=1
print(result)
```

Comment: What's the point in the length 1 arrays? just use numbers instead and get rid of result

Comment: sure but then you use `print(a,b)`

Comment: @NickA it shows the passing by reference and by value difference